# Why can't my Galaxy S4 load my email inbox after I changed the password?

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-4, google-account

I changed the password for my Gmail account a couple of days ago.  Since changing it, my Galaxy S4 cannot load the webpage.  Whenever I try to load Gmail in the web browser, it gets stuck loading and reloading the webpage, though no content ever resolves.

I've been trying to load the page daily for about a week now with no success.  I thought it may have the old password saved on my phone, but I enter the new password on the step before loading the page.

Tips?

Answer (score 0):

This may be slightly different on a GS4 but give this a try and let me know if you run into any issues:

- Go to Setting -> Apps -> Web Browser (Chrome, Firefox whatever browser you are using)
- Clear Cache
- Clear Data

And if that doesn't work: Uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Accounts and sign out and sign in with the new password.